# How to implement custom zoom in/out slider in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When UIImagePickerController sourceType is set to Camera, I want to replace system build-in zoom slider with my own slider. But after searching a while, I could not find the zoom in/out properties except cameraViewTransform. Is anyone knows how to control the camera's zoom in/out levels by code?
Thanks in advance.

Here are the build-in zoom slider.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the camera overlay view property in `UIImagePickerController` class?
Sounds like this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I know how to add custom controls to the camera layer,but how to zoom in or zoom out preview when sliding?